# How to flatten up embedded JSON into multiple documents

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : {
                   "Bangalore" :{ 
                                    "Address" : "MG Road",  
                                    "Phone"   : ["988888","888866","365656"]
                                },
                   "Mubmai" :   { 
                                    "Address" : "1st Main Road,West",  
                                    "Phone"   : ["21212","123123","544455"]
                                }
                }
}
```

Now I want to flatten up the JSON so that I get multiple JSON. For the above example the flattened output would be as follows:

```
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Bangalore",
    "Address" : "MG Road",
    "Phone"   : "988888"
},    
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Bangalore",
    "Address" : "MG Road",
    "Phone"   : "888866"
},    
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Bangalore",
    "Address" : "MG Road",
    "Phone"   : "365656"
},    
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Mubmai",
    "Address" : "1st Main Road,West",
    "Phone"   : "21212"
},    
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Mubmai",
    "Address" : "1st Main Road,West",
    "Phone"   : "123123"
},    
{
    "Company" : "ABC Company",
    "Place"   : "Mubmai",
    "Address" : "1st Main Road,West",
    "Phone"   : "544455"
}
```

And the JSON structure is not fixed it tend to change, but still the flattening has to work the same way. Is there any way to do this in Node.js?

Comment: If the JSON structure changes then I can't see how the logic to flatten it will be the same.

Comment: That is not just flattening. You are also unrolling/iterating on the array. What if there are multiple arrays in your JSON.

Comment: *"Is there any best way?"* What ways have you tried?

Comment: use `JSON.parse`, `isPlainObject`, `hasOwnProperty`, `recursion`. Get digging now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go : ([**jsb**](http://jsbin.com/oDivavU/5/edit))

```
var t = [];
for (p in a.Place)
{
    var _=a.Place[p]["Phone"];
    for (i = 0; i < _.length; i++)
    {
        var g = {
                  Company: a.Company,
                  Place: p,
                  Address: a.Place[p]["Address"]
                };
        g.Phone = _[i];
        t.push(g)
    }
}
```

[image]

If you add

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(t)
```

you'll get this

```
    [{"Company":"ABC Company","Place":"Bangalore","Address":"MG Road","Phone":"988888"},{"Company":"ABC Company","Place":"Bangalore","Address":"MG Road","Phone":"888866"},{"Company":"ABC Company","Place":"Bangalore","Address":"MG Road","Phone":"365656"},{"Company":"ABC Company","Place":"Mubmai","Address":"1st Main Road,West","Phone":"21212"},{"Company":"ABC Company","Place":"Mubmai","Address":"1st Main Road,West","Phone":"123123"},{"Company":"ABC 
Company","Place":"Mubmai","Address":"1st Main Road,West","Phone":"544455"}]
```

Comment: This assumes the OP is using Jquery, something not specified in the question because he's using Node.